# ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable."

Tags: ios, phonegap-build

OS: OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.1
XCode: Not installed
Application Loader 3.0 (620)
PhoneGap: 3.7.0
PhoneGap Build: Online (build.phonegap.com)

On Authenticating form iTunes step it gave ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable."

I have even upgraded to Phonegap 3.7.0 and I am using Github and build.phonegap.com to build IPA

In `info.plist` file

```
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
```

and

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.asa.filmcrew</string>
```

config.xml

```
<!-- Plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
<feature name="SplashScreen">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
<gap:platform name="ios" />
<gap:platform name="android" />
```

info.plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>13F34</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>ASA Film Crew</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>ASAFilmCrew</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>icon.png</string>
        <string>icon@2x.png</string>
        <string>icon-72.png</string>
        <string>icon-72@2x.png</string>
        <string>icon-60.png</string>
        <string>icon-60@2x.png</string>
        <string>icon-76.png</string>
        <string>icon-76@2x.png</string>
        <string>icon-60@3x.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.asa.filmcrew</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>ASA Film Crew</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2.9.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>iPhoneOS</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array/>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2.9.1</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>12B411</string>
    <key>DTPlatformName</key>
    <string>iphoneos</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>8.1</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>12B411</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>iphoneos8.1</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0610</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>6A1052d</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 480}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 480}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-667h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{375, 667}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-667h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{375, 667}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-736h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{414, 736}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-Landscape-736h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{414, 736}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{768, 1024}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{768, 1024}</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you using a production certificate when building?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon No. I am using Adhoc Dsitribution certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here.

> XCode: Not installed

XCode must be installed in order for Application Loader to work properly.

Source: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/error-itms-90085-no-architectures-in-the-binary-lipo-failed-to-detect-any-architectures-in-the-bundle-executable-n0mh4o6607t0c