# Uploading app to Apple Store Connect fails

Tags: ios, release, phonegap

I have built an ios app using Phonegap and I want to upload it to Apple Store Connect via Transporter (since I don't have XCode on my mac).

This is what happens when I upload my app to Transporter:

- the upload passes fine

- I click on the "verify" button

- it passes the authentication process but it fails with the below error:

[image: The error I get when I upload my .ipa using Transporter]

**Does anyone have a clue what could be the problem?**

I have also double-checked everything related to the app ID, apple certificate, and provision profile.

This is the first time I am releasing this app to Apple Store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149936/error-itms-90085-no-architectures-in-the-binary-lipo-failed-to-detect-any-arc)

Answer (score 0):

Install `Xcode`

and `Xcode` to Archive `.ipa` file. 

Xcode to Directly Upload `Appstore` or Export `ipa` and use `Transporter` to Deliver your App.